# AttributeError: module 'nextcord.client' has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I tried using cogs and it didnt go smoothly as expected since this is my first time using it. I was transferring my codes into their own cog and decided to run the bot for a test. One of my command failed to work and i was confused as it works before transferring. I am really new to nextcord.py please help me and acknowledge me.

the code in the cog:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import client
from nextcord.utils import get
from async_timeout import asyncio
import random

class King_Game(commands.Cog, name="King's Game"):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def king(self, ctx, mode=None):
        time = 10
        ktime = 2
        wtime = 1
        if mode == "1f":
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="King's Game", description="React to join.", color=0xfffb00)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends in {time}s")
            embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Xcm8MPn.gif")
            kmsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await kmsg.add_reaction("")

            await asyncio.sleep(time)

            new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
            players = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
            players.pop(players.index(client.user))
            print (players)

            king = random.choice(players)
            tembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Time is up!", description="Get ready to obey the king.",colour=0x54fffc)
            await ctx.send(embed=tembed)

            await asyncio.sleep(ktime)

            kembed = nextcord.Embed(title="King", description=f"{king.mention} is the **king**!", color=0xff1100)
            kembed.set_image(url="https://c.tenor.com/CVkAWrZvFAMAAAAC/sinister-smile.gif")
            await kmsg.remove_reaction(emoji="", member=king)
            await ctx.send(embed=kembed)

            wembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description="The **follower** will be revealed shortly.", colour=0x54fffc)
            wembed.set_footer(text="Get ready.")

            await asyncio.sleep(wtime)
            await ctx.send(embed=wembed)

            fmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
            remains = await fmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
            remains.pop(remains.index(client.user))
            print (remains)

            follower = random.choice(remains)
            print (follower)

            fembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description=f"{follower.mention} is the **follower**!", color=0x2f9e4d)
            fembed.set_footer(text="The follower must obey the king's order.")
            fembed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906110784822738984/934469807506620476/follower.gif")

            await asyncio.sleep(ktime)
            await ctx.send(embed=fembed)
        
        elif mode == "2f":
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="King's Game", description="React to join.", color=0xfffb00)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends in {time}s")
            embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Xcm8MPn.gif")
            kmsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await kmsg.add_reaction("")

            await asyncio.sleep(time)

            new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
            players = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
            players.pop(players.index(client.user))
            print (players)

            king = random.choice(players)
            tembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Time is up!", description="Get ready to obey the king.",colour=0x54fffc)
            await ctx.send(embed=tembed)

            await asyncio.sleep(ktime)

            kembed = nextcord.Embed(title="King", description=f"{king.mention} is the **king**!", color=0xff1100)
            kembed.set_image(url="https://c.tenor.com/CVkAWrZvFAMAAAAC/sinister-smile.gif")
            await kmsg.remove_reaction(emoji="", member=king)
            await ctx.send(embed=kembed)

            wembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Followers", description="The **followers** will be revealed shortly.", colour=0x54fffc)
            wembed.set_footer(text="Get ready.")

            await asyncio.sleep(wtime)
            await ctx.send(embed=wembed)

            fmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
            remains = await fmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
            remains.pop(remains.index(client.user))
            print (remains)

            follower1 = random.choice(remains)
            follower2 = random.choice(remains)
            print (follower1, follower2)

            fembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description=f"{follower1.mention} and {follower2.mention} are the **followers**!", color=0x2f9e4d)
            fembed.set_footer(text="The followers must obey the king's order.")
            fembed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906110784822738984/934469807506620476/follower.gif")

            await asyncio.sleep(ktime)
            await ctx.send(embed=fembed)
        elif mode == None:
            await ctx.send("Please specify the amount of followers. `1f or 2f`")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Mode is not supported, game will start with only 1 follower by default.")
            
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="King's Game", description="React to join.", color=0xfffb00)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends in {time}s")
            embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Xcm8MPn.gif")
            kmsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await kmsg.add_reaction("")

            await asyncio.sleep(time)

            new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
            players = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
            players.pop(players.index(client.user))
            print (players)

            king = random.choice(players)
            tembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Time is up!", description="Get ready to obey the king.",colour=0x54fffc)
            await ctx.send(embed=tembed)

            await asyncio.sleep(ktime)

            kembed = nextcord.Embed(title="King", description=f"{king.mention} is the **king**!", color=0xff1100)
            kembed.set_image(url="https://c.tenor.com/CVkAWrZvFAMAAAAC/sinister-smile.gif")
            await kmsg.remove_reaction(emoji="", member=king)
            await ctx.send(embed=kembed)

            wembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description="The **follower** will be revealed shortly.", colour=0x54fffc)
            wembed.set_footer(text="Get ready.")

            await asyncio.sleep(wtime)
            await ctx.send(embed=wembed)

            fmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
            remains = await fmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
            remains.pop(remains.index(client.user))
            print (remains)

            follower = random.choice(remains)
            print (follower)

            fembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description=f"{follower.mention} is the **follower**!", color=0x2f9e4d)
            fembed.set_footer(text="The follower must obey the king's order.")
            fembed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906110784822738984/934469807506620476/follower.gif")

            await asyncio.sleep(ktime)
            await ctx.send(embed=fembed)

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(King_Game(bot))
```

the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command king:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 168, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Bitter\VCS\Test-Bot-\Modules\kinggame\codes.py", line 28, in king
    players.pop(players.index(client.user))
AttributeError: module 'nextcord.client' has no attribute 'user'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1055, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 933, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 177, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'nextcord.client' has no attribute 'user'
```

before transferring:

```
@client.command()
async def king(ctx, mode=None):
    time = 10
    ktime = 2
    wtime = 1
    if mode == "1f":
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="King's Game", description="React to join.", color=0xfffb00)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends in {time}s")
        embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Xcm8MPn.gif")
        kmsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await kmsg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
        players = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        players.pop(players.index(client.user))
        print (players)

        king = random.choice(players)
        tembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Time is up!", description="Get ready to obey the king.",colour=0x54fffc)
        await ctx.send(embed=tembed)

        await asyncio.sleep(ktime)

        kembed = nextcord.Embed(title="King", description=f"{king.mention} is the **king**!", color=0xff1100)
        kembed.set_image(url="https://c.tenor.com/CVkAWrZvFAMAAAAC/sinister-smile.gif")
        await kmsg.remove_reaction(emoji="", member=king)
        await ctx.send(embed=kembed)

        wembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description="The **follower** will be revealed shortly.", colour=0x54fffc)
        wembed.set_footer(text="Get ready.")

        await asyncio.sleep(wtime)
        await ctx.send(embed=wembed)

        fmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
        remains = await fmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        remains.pop(remains.index(client.user))
        print (remains)

        follower = random.choice(remains)
        print (follower)

        fembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description=f"{follower.mention} is the **follower**!", color=0x2f9e4d)
        fembed.set_footer(text="The follower must obey the king's order.")
        fembed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906110784822738984/934469807506620476/follower.gif")

        await asyncio.sleep(ktime)
        await ctx.send(embed=fembed)
    
    elif mode == "2f":
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="King's Game", description="React to join.", color=0xfffb00)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends in {time}s")
        embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Xcm8MPn.gif")
        kmsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await kmsg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
        players = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        players.pop(players.index(client.user))
        print (players)

        king = random.choice(players)
        tembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Time is up!", description="Get ready to obey the king.",colour=0x54fffc)
        await ctx.send(embed=tembed)

        await asyncio.sleep(ktime)

        kembed = nextcord.Embed(title="King", description=f"{king.mention} is the **king**!", color=0xff1100)
        kembed.set_image(url="https://c.tenor.com/CVkAWrZvFAMAAAAC/sinister-smile.gif")
        await kmsg.remove_reaction(emoji="", member=king)
        await ctx.send(embed=kembed)

        wembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Followers", description="The **followers** will be revealed shortly.", colour=0x54fffc)
        wembed.set_footer(text="Get ready.")

        await asyncio.sleep(wtime)
        await ctx.send(embed=wembed)

        fmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
        remains = await fmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        remains.pop(remains.index(client.user))
        print (remains)

        follower1 = random.choice(remains)
        follower2 = random.choice(remains)
        print (follower1, follower2)

        fembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description=f"{follower1.mention} and {follower2.mention} are the **followers**!", color=0x2f9e4d)
        fembed.set_footer(text="The followers must obey the king's order.")
        fembed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906110784822738984/934469807506620476/follower.gif")

        await asyncio.sleep(ktime)
        await ctx.send(embed=fembed)
    elif mode == None:
        await ctx.send("Please specify the amount of followers. `1f or 2f`")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Mode is not supported, game will start with only 1 follower by default.")
        
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="King's Game", description="React to join.", color=0xfffb00)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends in {time}s")
        embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Xcm8MPn.gif")
        kmsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await kmsg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
        players = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        players.pop(players.index(client.user))
        print (players)

        king = random.choice(players)
        tembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Time is up!", description="Get ready to obey the king.",colour=0x54fffc)
        await ctx.send(embed=tembed)

        await asyncio.sleep(ktime)

        kembed = nextcord.Embed(title="King", description=f"{king.mention} is the **king**!", color=0xff1100)
        kembed.set_image(url="https://c.tenor.com/CVkAWrZvFAMAAAAC/sinister-smile.gif")
        await kmsg.remove_reaction(emoji="", member=king)
        await ctx.send(embed=kembed)

        wembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description="The **follower** will be revealed shortly.", colour=0x54fffc)
        wembed.set_footer(text="Get ready.")

        await asyncio.sleep(wtime)
        await ctx.send(embed=wembed)

        fmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(kmsg.id)
        remains = await fmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        remains.pop(remains.index(client.user))
        print (remains)

        follower = random.choice(remains)
        print (follower)

        fembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Follower", description=f"{follower.mention} is the **follower**!", color=0x2f9e4d)
        fembed.set_footer(text="The follower must obey the king's order.")
        fembed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906110784822738984/934469807506620476/follower.gif")

        await asyncio.sleep(ktime)
        await ctx.send(embed=fembed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `client` object you're using is not the discordpy client object, but in fact `nextcord.client` module you've imported.

```py
from nextcord import client
```

It seems like self.bot object is what you're looking for. `nextcord.commands.Bot` object is inherited from `nextcord.Client` and thus [does have `user` attribute.](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#nextcord.ext.commands.Bot.user)

You can change every `client.user` in your code to `self.bot.user`.

Comment: ah i see i changed it and it works, thank you!